# Does lldb support cd and pwd like gdb

Tags: gdb, lldb

In gdb, we can use 'pwd' to show the current folder, and use 'cd' to change the current working folder. Does lldb have the same commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In lldb, the debugger can create connections to `platforms` which it will use to upload files, run programs, etc.  By default, lldb is connected to the "host" platform, i.e. your local system.  You can use `platform shell` to run commands on the current platform, so to get the cwd, just do:

```
(lldb) platform shell pwd
```

You can't use `platform shell` to change the cwd, since this is a sub-shell, so it's effects don't persist past the execution of the sub-shell.  The `cwd` is a setting of the platform, so you change it with:

```
(lldb) platform settings -w <NEW_PATH>
```

Comment: Inghram, Does lldb have any short-cut command for this? I found the corresponding cmds in LLDB seem more verbose than GDB: https://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html. I feel it is hard to remember them. Is using the commands directly the best practice? Did anyone define any simplified commands to use?

Comment: lldb has an alias mechanism (see `help command alias` for more details) that allows quick access to commonly used commands.  lldb has some pre-made aliases (e.g. `s` and `n`, `bt` etc.)  But we didn't want to  over-fill the namespace of convenient short command words with the built-in ones, since that would make it less convenient for folks to tailor lldb based on what they most use.  So there is not a pre-built alias for `platform shell`.

Comment: This design point makes sense to me. Do we have any populate alias defined for lldb? I wanted to follow some convenience if people made it already. Thank you.

Comment: This was used as an example of command aliases at WWDC a couple of years ago, and `shell` was the alias name used. The default aliases include a one-letter alias `s` as well as `step` and exact matches win in the lldb command parser, so using `shell` doesn't make `s` ambiguous.  And there are no other "sh" commands.  So there's no reason not to use the obvious name.

Comment: But how can you print the working directory if you are remote debugging? For example `(lldb) file a.out` is supposed to load the local file `a.out` into the remote cwd. So I need to know what is the local cwd to be able to specify the relative path of `a.out`.